# Как написать SQL запрос по нескольким парам значений бинарного индекса

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две таблицы: DocType и Doc
У таблицы DocType primary key состоит из дух полей: App и Ext (приложение кот. его открывает и расширение). При чем (ну так получилось) по DocType.Ext однозначно можно определить DocType.App. Индекс по DocType.Ext добавлять нельзя.
В таблице Doc есть оба столбца из DocType.

[image: Примерная схема БД]
Картинка может не очень точная, но суть передает

В запрос приходит строка-массив DocType.Ext
Нужно написать select выбирающий все записи из Doc по DocType.Ext.
Проблема: Если написать в лоб

```
Doc.Ext = ANY(string_to_array(:ФильтрРасширенийДокументов::TEXT,','))
```

То PostgreSQL использует SeqScan, а не поиск по индексу. Как оптимизировать этот запрос?

Наверное нужно сначала создать временную таблицу в которой будут все пары App и Ext из Doc, которые пришли в фильтре. Но как этот результат запихнуть в where?

Comment: Сделайте в составном индексе Ext первым столбцом.

Comment: Есть структура и менять я её не могу, а так было бы проще добавить индекс по полю Ext и дело в шляпе

Comment: сколько записей в Doc? "То PostgreSQL использует SeqScan, а не поиск по индексу" какие есть индексы?

Comment: Если нет подходящего индекса, и изменять структуру вы не можете, тогда обращайтесь к администратору БД.
А создавать представления вы можете? Это может решить проблему.

Comment: 2 norbornen. Записей очень много (10^(7+)), поэтому при поиске по конкретной паре App+Ext, PostgreSQL считает поиск по индексам более выгодным, нежели чем SeqScan, если вы об этом. Есть и другие индексы, но они на суть дела (как мне кажется) не влияют

Comment: 2 msi. Не уверен в оптимальности создания представления, если я правильно понимаю, представление - это усложненная временная таблица. С учетом того что входной список расширений всегда разный - представление нужно будет перестраивать. Оптимально ли это? Давай предположим что я могу создавать представление, как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: @MiF, я не совсем понимаю проблему. в общем описанная ситуация выглядит странной, но если ты действительно ограничен в правах то сделай materialized view, триггер на обновление и развлекайся созданием индексов